# sql INSERT INTO with same ID Number

Tags: sql, insert-into

I'd like to make a sql table something like this.

Patient Num | Trial Number | Trial Date

```
 1      |      1       | 12/19/2014
 1      |      2       | 12/20/2014
 2      |      1       | 12/19/2014
 3      |      1       | 12/19/2014
```

I can do this with different patient numbers, but I can't do with same patient number. So I'd like to make this table with the same Patient Number but different trial numbers. My code is

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO PatientTestInfo(PatientNum, TrialNum, TrialDate)" & _
            "VALUES(" & PtNum_TextBox.Text & ",'" & TrialNum_TextBox.Text & "','" & TrialDate_PK.Value & "')"
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: I'm not the best at SQL, but what you sound like you want is a compound key, where both the PATNO and TRIALNO are used as primary keys.

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading this wrong, but I'm not clear on what the question is. Are you asking how to create a table to allow the behavior you describe, or are you asking why your insert is failing?

Comment: Which database are you using? Could you add the definition of your table - for micrsoft sql server you can use management studio by left clicking your table and click on `Script Table as` and then click on `create`. 

So you would like to be able to insert multiple records with the same patient-id into the database?

Comment: What Joe is referring to above is that your code is wide open to sql injection. You need to parameterize your queries or you going to face a tough battle at some point.

Answer (score 1):

If your field (Patient_Num, whatever) is a "Primary key" you cannot because is a UNIQUE number.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-primary-key.html

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because of your table definition, you cannot insert data with the same value if that column is primary key, so check your table definition. For your problem I think you should make both columns (together) primary key, to make rows unique even if they have same value for one of the columns.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I'm pretty new with Access so didn't know about this.

Comment: Np, you can mark one of the answers as correct to make the question useful for other people as well.